# Windows (freeware) audio plugin framework?

Tags: mixing, headphones, windows

I'm asking this question to help out a user on a sister SE site.

I'm Mac-based myself & know this is an easy task in Mac, using CoreAudio, SoundFlower, Rogue Amoeba etc.

Is there a comparable Windows framework that would allow audio processing plugins to be inserted to the 'standard' Windows audio chain, for non-professional use?

The end requirement is for a user with a specific hearing impairment who needs to be able to sum stereo to mono, adding different EQ to each channel before summing ?

This is a consumer-level, output-only requirement & needs to be done without recourse to any kind of DAW or offline processing.

My Google-fu is usually pretty good, but I'm having difficulty getting past all the VST plugin pages to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might like http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm .

Comment: @MackTuesday - thank you - The OP has already tried that, & http://jackaudio.org/ in the meantime. Outwardly it seems such a simple request, I can't believe it's actually so difficult to achieve outside a DAW. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know the sdks of [JUICE](http://www.juce.com/discover) and [libvlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/Libvlc/) can do it. The ffmpeg and vlc binaries can render as well using cmdline. The klite binaries i believe can do it too.

Any one of these are integrate-able into windows playback/recording or even the explorer shell too.

ffmpeg.org

videolan.org/vlc/

Answer (score 0):

You should look into PortAudio and RTAudio!